# Execute Robot Framework file from python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework

```
from subprocess import call
import os

call(['robot '+os.getcwd()+'\\aaa.robot'])
```

file_dir: D:/aaa/test/aaa.robot

script for now in same dir

```
Output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__init.py", line 7, in <module>
    call(['robot '+os.getcwd()+'\\aaa.robot'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init_
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execut
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Nie mo┐na odnalečŠ okreťlonego pliku
```

I just cant handle it. I dont get why in python tunning anything is so complicated :(

I want same result as this line (written directly to cmd):

```
/>robot aaa.robot
```

Comment: What is it you're hoping this program will do?

Comment: My bad, edited that to original post, thx.

Comment: This should be just ordinary startup script...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`subprocess` expects a list but you're inputting a string (`'robot '+os.getcwd()+'\\aaa.robot'`).

Try:

```
call(['C:/Python27/python.exe', '-m', 'robot', 'D:/aaa/test/aaa.robot'])
```

or

```
call(['C:/Python27/Scripts/robot.bat', 'D:/aaa/test/aaa.robot'])
```

Comment: First one has same result as in main topic

Comment: @user2678074 What is the full path to the `robot` program and are you absolutely sure that `D:/aaa/test/aaa.robot` is correct?

Comment: Yes. I added specially
print os.getcwd()
and the path is correct. Double checked

Comment: sorry for that :)
C:\Python27\Scripts\ride.py

btw...it is added to the PATH

Comment: @user2678074 That's not what I meant. `C:\Python27\Scripts\ride.py` is a python script, `robot` looks like an executable Windows binary or something. I asked about the `robot` program, not the python script. Is it `C:\Programs and Files whatever \robot\robot.exe` or something?

Comment: C:\Python27\Scripts\robot.bat

Comment: @user2678074 I updated my answer. Try the two new suggestions.

Comment: Well done! It worked! Thank you so much!

So, why python couldn't find 'robot' like command line did?

Comment: Great :) The only reason you can type `robot` in the terminal and run a program, is  because your computer knows that `robot` actually means ` `C:/Python27/Scripts/robot.bat`. `robot` is an alias or a "custom" nickname for an actual program. These "nicknames" and user settings are called environment variables. They only apply to your user. From Python's perspective, `robot` makes no sense - it needs the full path to the executable or you need to explicitly set `cwd=` in the subproces command.  Maybe this will work too: `call(['robot.bat', 'D:/aaa/test/aaa.robot'], cwd='C:/Python27/Scripts')`

Answer (score 17):

Here is another way

```
import robot

logFile = open('mylog.txt', 'w') 
robot.run("tmp.robot",stdout=logFile)
```

Comment: this is the best answer! detailed instruction of usage can be found in robot.run.py